Combination of the Dirichlet and Cauchy problems, find the PDE by which $\mathbb{E}_x M(X_{\tau_D \wedge t})$ is met
$X_t$ is an Itô diffusion process with continuous version, $\mathbb{L}_X$ is its generator. $D$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$. The stopping time $\tau_D$ is the first entry time of $D$, that is $\tau_D=\inf \{u\geqslant 0: X_u \in D\}$. Given a continuous function $M: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we know the function $F(x)=\mathbb{E}_x M(X_{\tau_D}),\ x \in D^c$, solves the  Dirichlet problem, that is
\begin{align*}
&\mathbb{L}_X F(x)=0,\ x \in D^c, \\
&F|_{\partial D^c}=M.
\end{align*}
The function $F(t,x)=\mathbb{E}_x M(X_t),\ x \in \mathbb{R},$ solves the Cauchy problem, that is
\begin{align*}
&\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}=\mathbb{L}_X F,\\ &F(0,x)=M(x).
\end{align*}
Now, I want to know whether the function $\tilde{F}(t,x)=\mathbb{E}_x M(X_{\tau_D \wedge t}),\ t\geqslant 0,\ x \in D^c$, satisfies the PDE,
\begin{align*}
&\frac{\partial \tilde{F}}{\partial t}=\mathbb{L}_X \tilde{F},\\ &\tilde{F}(0,x)=M(x),\\
&\tilde{F}|_{\partial D^c}=M.
\end{align*}

Define a new Markov process by setting $Y_s=(t-s,X_s)$ for $s\geqslant 0$. Then the infinitesimal generator of $Y$ is
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{L}_Y=-\frac{\partial}{\partial s}+\mathbb{L}_X.
\end{align*}
Consider the exit time of $Y$ from the open set $\tilde{C}=(0,\infty)\times D^c$ given by
\begin{align*}
\tilde{\tau}_{\tilde{D}}=\inf\{s\geqslant 0: Y_s\in \tilde{D}\},
\end{align*}
where $\tilde{D}=\tilde{C}^c$. Easily know, $\tilde{\tau}_{\tilde{D}}=t \wedge \tau_D$ and thus
\begin{align*}
\tilde{F}(t,x)=\mathbb{E}_{t,x} \tilde{M}(Y_{\tilde{\tau}_{\tilde{D}}}),
\end{align*}
where $\tilde{M}(u,x)=M(x)$ for $u\geqslant 0$. $\tilde{F}$ solves the Dirichlet problem with $(Y, \tilde{D})$, thus we have
\begin{align*}
&\mathbb{L}_Y\tilde{F}=0,\ (t,x)\in \tilde{C},\\ &\tilde{F}|_{\partial \tilde{C}}=\tilde{M}.
\end{align*}
